# Take photo of given size Android

Tags: android, image, resize, android-camera

I'm developing an application that takes a photo and saves it in Android/data/package/files. I would like to reduce storage used, so I would like to resize the photo before saving it. For the moment I'm calling new intent passing as extra the output path. Is possible to pass also the size wanted or is possible to have the bitmap before saving it?

```
public void takePicture(View view){
    Intent pictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File f = new File(getPath(nameEdit.getText().toString()));
    path = f.getAbsolutePath();
    pictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
    if (pictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null){
        startActivityForResult(pictureIntent,REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is possible to pass also the size wanted

No.

> is possible to have the bitmap before saving it?

Not really. You could write your own `ContentProvider` and use a `Uri` for that, rather than a file. When the camera app tries saving the content, you would get that information in memory first. However, you will then crash with an `OutOfMemoryError`, as you will not have enough heap space to hold a full-resolution photo, in all likelihood.

You can use `BitmapFactory` with `inSampleSize` set in the `BitmapFactory.Options` to read in the file once it has been written by the camera, save the resized image as you see fit, then delete the full-resolution image. Or, skip `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, and you will get a thumbnail image returned to you, obtained by calling `getExtra("data")` on the `Intent` passed into `onHandleIntent()`.

Comment: I thought too of saving it, resize it and then delete the full-size photo, but I was hoping in something more efficient. If is not possible I'm going to do it in this way. Thank you